# T-SQL - Value does not match at least one item in list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have an MS SQL table with several columns, each for different employee roles, and a corresponding column for each indicating whether the current employee in that role is active, on leave, terminated, etc. Due to dependency on an external data source, the fields aren't really normalized.

I'm looking to run a query to return all of the rows where **at least one** of the 'is active' columns is **not** equal to 'ACTIVE'. There are several possible values other than Active.

I know one of the longer ways to do this would be

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
WHERE IsActive1 <> 'ACTIVE' OR
      IsActive2 <> 'ACTIVE' OR
      IsActive3 <> 'ACTIVE' OR
      IsActive4 <> 'ACTIVE' OR
... etc
```

Just wondering if there is a shorter way, possibly more efficient way to do this. I've seen plenty of solutions for finding a match across multiple columns, but not one for looking for non-matches.

Comment: why would you way be longer? you don't list a database engine, but it will be tough to use an index on this query.  unless your database engine supports some tricks, like SQL Server's filtered indexes or something, similar you will table scan no matter what you do.

Comment: Can the columns contain `NULL` values?

Comment: MS SQL Server db engine is implied in the title (TSQL). I'm asking if my way is longer than something else. Tell me about these SQL Server tricks you speak of :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, NULLs are possible

Comment: I'm not sure which version of SQL server you are using. if 2008 or above, look into filtered indexes, they are basically an index that has a where clause.  you would then have an index containing only the rows that have an "inactive"

Comment: I'm on 2008 R2, which looks like it supports the filtered indexes. I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: @km. You can't use an `or` in filtered indexes. Joe you could just create a computed column on the table with `case when ... then 1 else 0 end` and index that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that this is more elegant, but you could do something like this:

```
where replace(IsActive1 + IsActive2 + IsActive3 + . . .,
              'ACTIVE', '') <> ''
```

Note that if the values could be `NULL`, then you would need to replace them with something else.  Also, this assumes that the strings themselves are not empty.

EDIT:

If you want to do this efficiently *and* want the code to look good, add a computed column and build an index on that column:

```
alter table mytable
    add IsAllActive as (case when IsActive1 = 'ACTIVE' and
                                  IsActive2 = 'ACTIVE' and
                                  . . .
                             then 'ACTIVE'
                             else 'INACTIVE'
                        end);

create index mytable_IsAllActive on mytable(IsAllActive);
```

You might want to add other relevant columns to the index as well.

Comment: Going to research Filtered indexes a bit more just to get familiar with them, but computed column looks like it's the way to go for my question

Answer (score 0):

Try using a filtered index, which is quite limited in what you can include in the `WHERE` clause:

```
--simulate your existing table
create table Test (RowID int identity(1,1) primary key
                  ,c1 varchar(10), c2 varchar(10),c3 varchar(10),c4 varchar(10)
                  )
go
--simulate your existing data
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('ACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE')        --1
                      , ('ACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE')        --2  
                      , ('ACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE')        --3
                      , ('INACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE')      --4 <Inactive
                      , ('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE')      --5 <Inactive
                      , ('ACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE','ACTIVE')      --6 <Inactive
                      , ('ACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE')      --7 <Inactive
                      , ('INACTIVE','ACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE')    --8 <Inactive
                      , ('INACTIVE','ACTIVE','INACTIVE','INACTIVE')  --9 <Inactive
                      , ('INACTIVE','INACTIVE','INACTIVE','INACTIVE')--10<Inactive
go

--what you need to add to your existing table
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX fIX_Test_c1 ON Test(c1) WHERE C1 !='ACTIVE'
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX fIX_Test_c2 ON Test(c2) WHERE C2 !='ACTIVE'
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX fIX_Test_c3 ON Test(c3) WHERE C3 !='ACTIVE'
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX fIX_Test_c4 ON Test(c4) WHERE C4 !='ACTIVE'

--your query o get the data
      SELECT * FROM Test WHERE c1 !='ACTIVE'
UNION SELECT * FROM Test WHERE c2 !='ACTIVE'
UNION SELECT * FROM Test WHERE c3 !='ACTIVE'
UNION SELECT * FROM Test WHERE c4 !='ACTIVE'
```

you could try a persisted computed column, with an index:

```
ALTER TABLE Test ADD C_Summary AS (LEFT(ISNULL(c1,'Z'),1)+LEFT(ISNULL(c1,'Z'),1)+LEFT(ISNULL(c1,'Z'),1)+LEFT(ISNULL(c1,'Z'),1))
go
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX fIX_Test_C_Summary ON Test(C_Summary) 
go

select * from test WHERE C_Summary !='AAAA'
```

You'll have to try these (and other variations) out on your data, which can skew the index usage.  Also, you might want to try changing the table design, where you split all the C1, C2, C3, C4,... columns into different rows in a child table.  You could then do a single filtered index on that table.